Reply Script Gmail
I am trying to get a script running that will allow me to do the following:
After sending recipient X an email and NOT receiving a response, I want to be able to send recipient X a "Kind Reminder Email" in response to the original email that I had sent recipient X (I want it to be in the same thread so that recipient X can reference the original email in the thread).
This is what I have got going so far:
function replyToSelectedEmails() {
  // Prompt the user to enter the label name
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Enter the label name of emails you want to reply to:');
  var labelName = response.getResponseText();
  
  if (response.getSelectedButton() != ui.Button.OK) {
    ui.alert('No label name entered. Exiting.');
    return;
  }

  // Prompt the user to enter the reply message
  response = ui.prompt('Enter your reply message:');
  var replyMessage = response.getResponseText();

  if (response.getSelectedButton() != ui.Button.OK) {
    ui.alert('No reply message entered. Exiting.');
    return;
  }

  // Get the label
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labelName);

  if (label == null) {
    ui.alert('Label not found!');
    return;
  }

  // Get threads with the specified label
  var threads = label.getThreads();

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var thread = threads[i];
    var messages = thread.getMessages();
    
    // Get the recipient's email address from the first message in the thread
    var originalMessage = messages[0];
    var recipientEmails = originalMessage.getTo();
    var recipientEmail = recipientEmails[0]; // Take the first email address

    // Reply to the last message in the thread
    var lastMessage = messages[messages.length - 1];
    lastMessage.reply({
      htmlBody: replyMessage,
      name: 'name', // Replace with the desired sender's name
      to: recipientEmail // Reply to the recipient of the original email
    });
  }

  ui.alert('Replied to ' + threads.length + ' emails.');
}


It didn't do the following:
Respond to the email. It sends me an email instead.
The email didn't have my name (it displayed by email in the From section: ((despite me editing name: 'name', // Replace with the desired sender's name with my name)
Email didn't have the kind reminder msg I entered when prompted and instead had [object Object]
any and all help appreciated.
